# please help me out its very confusing java code

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};

    int i=0;
    while (i<20)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[?]); 
    }

}}
```

what should we write in place of ? so that `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception do not occur and the output is as follows?

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the array index to always be one of {0, 1, 2, 3}.

The mod n (%n) operation will get you result among [0, n-1].

So you can write it like:

```
System.out.println(arr[(i++)%4]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use modulu 4, since that would give you integers between 0 and 3, which are the indices of your array :

```
System.out.println(arr[i%4]);
```

But don't forget to increment i.

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};

int i=0;
while (i<20)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i%4]); 
    i++;
}
```

A more succinct solution (though less readable in my opinion), would be to combine the two statements :

```
System.out.println(arr[(i++)%4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution one can vary the length of the array. And 'i' can take any value. So that Array Index Out Of Bound exception do not occur.

```
System.out.print(arr[i++%arr.length]);
```